# How to find a specific number from a user inputed list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, find

I want the program to find the number of times a particular number occurs within a list. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def list1():
    numInput = input("Enter numbers separated by commas: ")
    numList = numInput.split(",")
    numFind = int(input("Enter a number to look for: "))
    count = 0
    for num in numList:
        if num == numFind:
            count += 1
    length = len(numList)
    # dividing how many times the input number was entered 
    # by the length of the list to find the %
    fraction = count / length
    print("Apeared",count,"times")
    print("Constitutes",fraction,"% of this data set")
list1()
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what the actual problem is. Also, are you using Python 3.x?

Comment: list.count(thint_to_find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numList` isn't a list of numbers, it's a list of strings. Try converting to integer before comparing to `numFind`.

```
    if int(num) == numFind:
```

Alternatively, leave `numFind` as a string:

```
numFind = input("Enter a number to look for: ")
```

... Although this may introduce some complications, e.g. if the user enters `1, 2, 3, 4` as their list (note the spaces) and `2` as their number, It will say "Appeared 0 time" because `" 2"` and `"2"` won't compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with the code, First you are comparing `int` with `str` and the second is `count / length`. In Python when you divide `int` with `int` you get an `int` returned not a `float` (as  expected.) so `fraction = flost(count) / length` would work for you , also you need to convert all the elements in the list to integers which can be done as :

```
numList = map(int, numInput.split(","))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys that was so simple I feel stupid now. I also see the question was asked already, sorry this was my first question I'll be more vigilant on future posts.

Comment: "In Python when you divide int with int you get an int returned not a float". Partially agree. In 2.7 you get an int. in 3.X you can get a float.

Comment: @Kevin , Thanks for the insight, But I guess it is often a good practise to explicitly convert to `floats` when precision is needed, Just to be on a safer side to avoid any confusion